# PySpark: Fastest way of counting values in multiple columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to count a value in several columns and I want all those individual count for each column in a list.

Is there a faster/better way of doing this? Because my solution takes quite some time.

```
dataframe.cache()
list = [dataframe.filter(col(str(i)) == "value").count() for i in range(150)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional count aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.agg(*[
    F.count(F.when(F.col(str(i)) == "value", 1)).alias(i) 
    for i in range(150)
])

result = df2.toPandas().transpose()[0].tolist()
```

Comment: Do you expect your solution to be faster than mine?

Comment: I suppose it should be. Feel free to test it on your data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach/design

1. write a map function for each row of the data frame like this:

```py
VALUE = 'value'

def row_mapper(df_row):
    return [each == VALUE for each in df_row]
```

2. write a reduce function for data frame that takes 2 two rows as input:

```py
def reduce_rows(df_row1, df_row2):
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(df_row1, df_row2)]
```

**Note**: these are simple python function to help you understand not some udf functions you can directly apply on PySpark.

Comment: Do you expect your solutions to be faster than mine?

Comment: this is not even a spark solution, so I don't think so

Comment: I don't even understand the second one.

Comment: @Dusty - yes, both approaches are different ! Your approach should be faster if the data is stored & executed in columnar fashion which is possible if the data is in parquet or any columnar format or columnar data store otherwise, my approach is faster which reads each row only once and its simple. One map and one reduce operation. Please share you view & stats if possible